# Format a date using current locale in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I can format a date with the following layout.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>{{event.date | date : 'medium' }}</h2>
</div>
```

The problem is: the format is always the same.

How can I format a date using current locale of the phone given that I do not know the locale in advance and locale can change while the program is running?

Comment: [globalization.dateToString](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.dateToString) would be the method to use. You could wrap that in a custom filter, but I'm not sure if the method is synchronous or not. If not, you would need to put the functionality into a service

Comment: It should work hope you are including the locale specific file angular comes with angular-locale_*.js

Comment: @RGraham dateToString is asynchronous. could you show how to put it into a service so I could use it in a binding?

Comment: @Chandermani Unfortunately, AngularJS uses locale from last included angular-locale_*.js and not a current locale. I mean, if I include `ru-ru` and `de-de` locales (in that order) and make Russian locale current I still get Deutsch month names.